# Firebase Storage OnSuccessListeners not successful in time

Tags: android, gridview, firebase, firebase-storage

After thorough debugging, I have concluded that the reason my `GridView` is not displaying any of my Images is because both of my `OnSuccessListeners` in `getData()` and `getImage()` from when I get the thumbnail and title from Firebase Storage are not successful yet.

I do all of this in my `getData()` method, which I call after the user selects their Google Place in `onActivityResult`. The method should instantiate a new `ImageItem`(Bitmap, String) but is returning a null `ImageItem` due to the `onSucessListeners` not being successful yet. Any ideas?

```
    private void getData() {
        imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child((String) p.getName()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iter = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(myUrl);
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    hasImage = false;
                    hasTitle = false;
                    HashMap<String, String> m = (HashMap<String, String>) iter.next().getValue();
                    String v = m.get("url");
                    Log.d("url", v);

                    String bu = m.get("bucket");
                    Log.d("bucket", bu);
                    b = getImage(bu, v);
                    StorageReference iR = httpsReference.child(bu).child("thumb");

                    httpsReference.child(bu).getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                            // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
                            t = storageMetadata.getCustomMetadata("title");
                            hasTitle = true;
                            Log.d("title", t);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            Log.d("error", "ERROr");
                            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                        }
                    });


                    gridAdapter.data.add(new ImageItem(b, t, bu, v));


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }



public Bitmap getImage(String bx, String vu) {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(myUrl);


    String v = vu;
    Log.d("url", v);

    String bu = bx;
    Log.d("bucket", bu);
    StorageReference iR = httpsReference.child(bu).child("thumb");

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    iR.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            hasImage = true;
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
    return b;
}
}
```

****************UPDATE 1/7/2017*********************

```
 private void getData() {
        imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child((String) p.getName()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iter = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                final StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://socialnetwork-4b0c9.appspot.com");
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    hasImage = false;
                    hasTitle = false;
                    HashMap<String, String> m = (HashMap<String, String>) iter.next().getValue();
                    final String v = m.get("url");
                    Log.d("url", v);

                    final String bu = m.get("bucket");
                    Log.d("bucket", bu);
                    StorageReference iR = httpsReference.child(bu).child("thumb");
                    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
                    iR.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                            // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
                            b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                            httpsReference.child(bu).getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                                    // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
                                    t = storageMetadata.getCustomMetadata("title");
                                    hasTitle = true;
                                    gridAdapter.data.add(new ImageItem(b, t, bu, v));
                                    Log.d("title", t);
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    Log.d("error", "ERROr");
                                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle any errors
                        }
                    });


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

************************METHOD PERTAINING TO GRIDVIEW AND GRIDADAPTER*********

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                p = place;

                gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_View);

                gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout);
                getData();
                gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        //Create intent
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("bucket", item.getBucket());
                        intent.putExtra("dUrl", item.getdUrl());


                        //Start details activity
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });


            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.


            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Firebase Storage are you using? Is there an error? Can you please post a shorter example of this behavior, without the app specific logic? It's super hard to read 500 LoC, entirely in the SO code snippet. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info on building better examples.

Comment: Also use a `ChildEventListener` instead of a `SingleEventListener` + parsing all the data manually. The Firebase DB does a lot of the heavy lifting for you if you let it help you :) https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for your response. I have edited my question to show only the two methods my issue peratins to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic asynchronous programming issue:

```
var a = 1;

incrementAsync(function() {
  a = 2;
});

console.log(a);  // prints 1 because the function hasn't returned yet
```

You need to instead perform the action in the async function:

```
var a = 1;

incrementAsync(function() {
  a = 2;
  console.log(a);  // prints 2 now
});
```

So I'd re-write your function as:

```
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
FirebaseStorage mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

mDatabase.getReference("...").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        ModelObject modelObject = storage.getValue(ModelObject.class);
        // Or just download the object here...
        mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(modelObject.getUrl()).getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                String title = storageMetadata.getCustomMetadata("title");
                gridAdapter.data.add(...);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            }
        });
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: I added my implementation above. I believe the thumbnail and title are successfully being downloaded based on my logs. I now download image first then in its onSucess I download the metadata. However, my adapter is now not loading the thumbnail and its title? Thank you for your help. I have been stuck on this for weeks.